# Fabric - export variable to virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, fabric

so I have fabric 1.14.0 and I'm trying to export environmental variable to my virtualenv. What Im doing is this:

```
with prefix('source venv/bin/activate'):
     run('export X_APP=xxx')
```

But after, when I check the variables with 'printenv' while having venv activated, the variable X_APP is not there. Is there something wrong with my process?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see any answer anywhere on the internet, so I will respond to my question. The way I fixed it is by adding the export command to the end of venv/bin/activate file.

```
sudo echo 'export X_APP=xxx' >> venv/bin/activate
```

This way the variable will export into virtualenv environment every time the venv is activated.